# how can I resolve sweetalert background distortion?

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpQLS.png)

Upper image is the Sign-in page.

I added sweetalert, and it goes wrong like below.
(the alert set in the middel, and **my sign-in form goes up! It should be located in the middle!**)

[image: 2]

(I added the alert appear when the ID or password value is null or empty.)

login equals sign-in

what's wrong with my code?

Here is my full code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.101.0">
    <title>Floating labels example · Bootstrap v4.6</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <!--    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/product/">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }

    </style>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/css/floating-labels.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-signin" style="max-width: 520px">
    <div class="text-center mb-4">
        <!--   TODO 로그인페이지 로고 추가할 자리         -->
        <!--            <img class="mb-4" src="/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">-->
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">로그인 </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
        <input id="user_id" class="form-control" placeholder="id" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputId">ID를 입력하세요</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <label for="inputPassword">Password를 입력하세요</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control" id="loginBtn" onclick="login()">로그인</button>
    </div>

    <hr class="mb-4">

    <div class="btn-group row" style="width:100%; --bs-gutter-x: 0">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block col-4" type="button" style="font-size:16px;">아이디
            찾기
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block col-4" type="button" style="font-size:16px;">비밀번호
            찾기
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block col-4" type="button" style="font-size:16px;"
                onclick="joinBtn()">회원가입
        </button>
    </div>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted text-center">&copy; 2017-2022</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    var input = document.getElementById("password");

    input.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("loginBtn").click();
        }
    });

    var passwordForm = document.querySelector("#password");

    function login() {
        let userIdValue = document.querySelector("#user_id").value;
        let passwordValue = document.querySelector("#password").value;

        if (userIdValue == null || userIdValue == "") {
            document.querySelector("#user_id").focus();
            Swal.fire(
                    'ID가 비었습니다!',
                    '로그인 할 계정의 ID를 입력해주세요!',
                    'question'
            )
            return;
        }

        if (passwordValue == null || passwordValue == "") {
            document.querySelector("#password").focus();
            Swal.fire(
                    '비밀번호가 비었습니다!',
                    '로그인 할 계정의 비밀번호를 입력해주세요!',
                    'question'
            )
            return;
        }

        let info = {
            userId: userIdValue,
            password: passwordValue
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/login/check/api",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/Json",
            data: JSON.stringify(info),
            success: function (a) {
                location.href = "/"
            },
            error: function (a, b) {
                let errorA = a
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: '로그인 실패',
                    text: errorA.responseText,
                })
                //alert(a.responseText);
            }
        })
    }


    function joinBtn() {
        location.href = "/join/form"
    }

</script>
```

let me know how can I solve this problem

Before the alert comes out, I think the HTML should be on the screen first to solve the problem, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please give a complete and minimal code example. Your current example can't be run because of missing dependencies like sweetalert and functions like `joinBtn`

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: where does it go wrong?

Comment: I added a complete code and some more explain about my problem thx guys:)